# mongodump - not authenticating when using secondary

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I am having an issue that I cannot figure out.  When I do a backup from the primary the dump works.  When I do it from the secondary it always get the error "listDatabases requires authentication".

If I connect with mongo using the same user I **can** run this on both primary and secondary.  (rs.slaveOk() needed for secondary)

```
db.adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } )
```

The user has these roles.

```
    {
        "role" : "backup",
        "db" : "admin"
    },
    {
        "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
        "db" : "admin"
    },
    {
        "role" : "restore",
        "db" : "admin"
    },
    {
        "role" : "root",
        "db" : "admin"
    }
```

I can see the user has these roles on both the primary and secondary.

However this command fails when run on secondary:

```
mongodump --archive=dump.gz --gzip --oplog --port xxxxx --username xx --password xx --authenticationDatabase=admin  
Failed: error creating intents to dump: error getting database names: (Unauthorized) command listDatabases requires authentication
```

I noticed that I get the same error even if I enter invalid passwords / user.

However on primary a bad password will get this error:

```
Failed: can't create session: could not connect to server: connection() : auth error: sasl conversation error: unable to authenticate using mechanism "SCRAM-SHA-256": (AuthenticationFailed) Authentication failed.
```

This tells me that the secondary is not trying to authenticate. 
How can I get the secondary to perform the database dump when authentication is required?

Thank you

Comment: Encountering the exact same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: No. I ended up removing the authentication and placing mongo on a private network go get around this issue.